# "Да... кажется, нашла". Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Здесь "кажется" — вводное слово, но даже являясь таковым, в некоторых случаях оно не обособляется.

Ставится ли здесь запятая? В каких случаях вводное не обособляется?

Comment: @shampar Мне кажется, что зря Вы убрали метку "запятые", т. к. для обособления вводных слов иногда используется тире. А здесь вопрос стоит именно о запятой.

Comment: Пунктуация, сдаётся, понятие ёмкое. В тексте вопроса, к тому же, слово «запятая» упоминается не один раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**КАЖЕТСЯ**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/302/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

1. Вводное слово. То же, что **вероятно, по-видимому, наверное** или **ведь, же**.
   Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

*Я пожирал его очами, я право, кажется, забывал мигать, глядя на него* (Тургенев).

*Онегин, я тогда моложе,

Я лучше, кажется, была…*
А. С. Пушкин

**Да… кажется, нашла.** (Да, кажется, нашла. — Троеточие поглощает первую запятую.)

Вводное слово "кажется" не всегда выделяется запятыми. Пунктуация зависит от строения предложения, наличия в нём обособленных членов.
Если вводное слово находится в начале или конце уже обособленного оборота, то вторая запятая не ставится.

**Причастный оборот:**
Я сейчас только вспомнила эти слова, **кажется** услышанные в далеком детстве от моей мудрой бабушки Марии.

**Деепричастный оборот:**
**Кажется** даже не заметив чистоты свежевымытого пола, мальчишка прошлепал босиком прямо к накрытому столу.

**Обороты с присоединением, уточнением, пояснением:**
Наш парт­нер вер­нет­ся из поезд­ки зав­тра, **кажет­ся** толь­ко вече­ром.
Его сти­хи, **кажет­ся** доволь­но инте­рес­ные, про­зву­ча­ли вче­ра в пере­да­че.
Эти сведения почерпнуты из нового, **кажется** специально для данного случая составленного, отчёта.

В таких слу­ча­ях ввод­ное сло­во при­над­ле­жит обо­ро­ту, тес­но свя­за­но с ним по смыс­лу и не выде­ля­ет­ся запя­той, что­бы избе­жать нагро­мож­де­ния зна­ков пре­пи­на­ния.
[**Когда слово "кажется" не выделяется запятыми**](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kazhetsya-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi.html)

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении запятая нужна. Если Вы хотите знать, при каких обстоятельствах слово *кажется* не обособляется, даже являясь вводным, то Вам следует понять, что здесь действуют общие правила для вводных слов; они слишком громоздки для цитирование в рамках ответа, но с ними можно ознакомиться, например, [здесь](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=c3c180cc-a4c7-4db3-bedf-d82cf2730baf).